# If statement True is ignored and always executes Else

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to check column 1 for any matches with a `TextBox`.

If there is a match, update a few textboxes with worksheet data. If there is no match, then display a MsgBox. Here's a snippet of my code:

```vb
Private Sub CheckPCButton_Click()                                                                      
    Dim totRows As Long, i As Long
    totRows = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To totRows
        If Trim(UCase(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1))) = Trim(UCase(TextBox22.Text)) Then           
            TextBox22.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)
            TextBox25.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 2)
            TextBox24.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 3)
            TextBox23.Text = "Approved"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not approved"                                                                                                                                                    
            Exit For
        End If 
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Ignore". What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: The `If` is not ignored, `Trim(UCase(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1))) = Trim(UCase(TextBox22.Text))` is simply never `TRUE`. Print both `Trim(UCase(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)))` and `Trim(UCase(TextBox22.Text))` and compare both values on screen.

Comment: Thanks for your time to respond. I mean Even if the Statement in the IF condition is true, it always brings up the MsgBox (which it shouldn't if condition is true). So I guess it always jumps to the Else bit, hence it always brings up the MsgBox regardless the condition being true or not

Comment: I expect the condition to show that a postcode is approved if the value in the textbox is found in the Database, but instead, it always brings up the Else statement even if postcode is in the database. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Write a `stop`at the begining of the procedure, click the button, and then put this in the [immediate window](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/), hit enter and tell us what it returns `? Trim(UCase(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1))) = Trim(UCase(TextBox22.Text))` then just `? Trim(UCase(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)))` and then `? Trim(UCase(TextBox22.Text))`

Comment: Thanks for your response Ricardo, but you lost me there. DO you mean I should write the word "stop" at the just before the IF statement? And which button to click then? Also, should I expect a pop window when that is done to input the code above? Sorry, I am a dummy in VBA Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your code's logic correct? My understanding of your code is:

1. Start with `ROW = 2`
2. Check if `Cells(ROW,1)` and `TextBox22` match.
3. If they do match, update the userform **including** updating `TextBox22`
4. Now advance to the next `ROW` and repeat starting at step 2
5. Steps 2, 3, 4 will repeat until a mismatch is encountered
6. If there is no match, show a `MsgBox`

So unless all of the values in `Column 1` match what is initially in `TextBox22`, you're eventually going to get the `MsgBox`.

### Added based on comment from original poster

I think this code does what you're after

```
Private Sub CheckPCButton_Click()
    Dim MatchFound as boolean
    Dim totRows As Long, i As Long
    totRows = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    MatchFound = False
    For i = 2 To totRows
        If Trim(UCase(Sheet4.Cells(i, 1))) = Trim(UCase(TextBox22.Text)) Then           
            TextBox22.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 1)
            TextBox25.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 2)
            TextBox24.Text = Sheet4.Cells(i, 3)
            TextBox23.Text = "Approved"
            MatchFound = True
            Exit For
        End If 
    Next i
    If Not MatchFound Then MsgBox "Not approved"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. That is probably my mistake. And I would not be surprised if the logic is incorrect as I am a fresh newbie to VBA Excel. How to get this  logic correct then please? All I am trying to do is to check column 1 and if there is minimum 1 match then to add the respective values from sheet2 to textboxes. And if there is no match at all, then display the MsgBox. But atm, I always get the MsgBox, even if there is a match. So what you said makes sense, if you could correct the logic or guide me through, that would be great .
Cheers

Comment: This works exactly how I expected it to now. Many thanks xidgel, you're a legend